# Julia throwing matrix multiplication error when matrix dimensions are correct

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply a 1000x1000 matrix with a 1000x2 matrix. However, I keep getting an error that the dimensions of the matrices are incorrect. I am brand new to Julia and am not sure what the issue is exactly, so any help would be great. Upon further inspection it seems like it is related to my use of `rand` command, but I'm not sure how to get it to output the matrix with the dimensions I'm looking for. I have commented on the line that is causing the issue, and commenting on the rand lines as well in the reprex below.

```
## packages
using Random, Distributions, LinearAlgebra

## set seed
Random.seed!(02192024);

# generate the distribution for X
μ = zeros(2);
Σ = [1 0; 0 1];
d = MvNormal(μ, Σ);
X = rand(d, 1000, 2); # one use of rand 

# generate the distribution for Z 
μ = zeros(3);
Σ = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];
zd = MvNormal(μ, Σ);
Z = rand(zd, 1000, 3); # another use of rand

# generate the distribution for Y
Y = randn(1000, 1);

# define the projection matrix
Pz = Z * inv(Z'*Z) * Z';

# define X̂ and Ŷ
X̂ = Pz * X; # this is the line with the error
Ŷ = Pz * Y; # this line does NOT throw an error
```

I have looked up the error in question, but none of the results have been applicable to my particular issue. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at `X`? Sampling from an `MvNormal` with `rand(d, 1000)` already gives you a 2x1000 `Matrix{Float64}`. You likely do not want a 2x1000 `Matrix{Vector{Float64}}`.

Comment: As the previous comment said, you don't need to specify for `rand` the dimension 2 or 3, since it is embedded in the distribution `d` or `zd`, just `rand(d,1000)` and `rand(zd, 1000)` is what you want.

Comment: Ahh that was the trick! Is there any way to get the output to be a 1000x2 rather than a 2x1000 or is that just the default and we transpose after?

Comment: @WildcatPhD the comment by Dan Getz contains the solution, i.e. using `rand(d,1000)` and `rand(zd,1000)` without the third argument. Perhaps you can write that up as a complete answer and mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify for rand the dimension 2 or 3, since it is embedded in the distribution d or zd, just use rand(d,1000) and rand(zd, 1000).